# Flutter Desktop File Picker Result files. Bytes return null Error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I am building Flutter Desktop/Web Application. I use Flutter file_picker 4.02 pub its
perfect working on flutter web after  convert desktop app it have error  in file selection return

> **file.byte**  **return value null**

FilePickerResult? `result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();`

```
if (result != null) {
  PlatformFile file = result.files.first;

  print(file.name);
  **print(file.bytes);**
  print(file.size);
  print(file.extension);
  print(file.path);
 


} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

I need to get selected results as  byte ?

> Flutter channels: Dev
> file_picker: ^4.0.2

Comment: It seems you have opened an issue with them. That's good, but you have not actually filled out their template. Maybe it's best to go back and fill in their bug report template properly.

Answer (score 0):

I select only one file to upload from chrome.   I use Stream.fromIterable to get map the bytes into a array.  I create a MultipartFile with the filename,filesize and bytes array.  Next, I use dio to post the FormData to an webapi.   The [FromForm] is used to extract data from the formData posted by dio.  IFormData binds to the multipart form data.

```
  FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type:  FileType.any, allowMultiple: false);

  var fileName = result.files.first.name;
  var fileSize = fileBytes.length;

  FormData formData=FormData.fromMap({
    'id':id,
    'name':submitter,
    'file': MultipartFile(
  Stream.fromIterable(fileBytes.map((e) => [e])),
  fileSize,
  filename: fileName,
)}) ;

var url = Uri.parse(_BASE_URL + 'api/review/upload');
Dio dio=new Dio();
try
{
   String token = this.dataCache?.login?.jwtToken??"";
   Options options=new Options(
      contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,
      headers:{
        Headers.contentLengthHeader: formFile.length,
      }
   );
   options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
   
   dio.post(url.toString(),data:formFile, options:options);
```

Webapi

```
 public class FlutterFormData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocument([FromForm] FlutterFormData 
    formData, string name)
    {
        String retVal = "unprocessed";
        if (formData.file != null)
        {

            if (formData.file.Length > 0)
            {
                var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

                using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                {
                    await formData.file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    retVal = "Processed";
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok(retVal);
    }
```